# Wi-Fi 101: Using my router's Wi-Fi and WIRED connections SIMULTANEOUSLY

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

(I'm on a Mac, BTW.)

I have a [Linksys WRT54G2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54G2) that has been serving as our Wi-Fi hub for some time.  We love it.

Today I bought a Blu-ray players with Internet capabilities (streaming NetFlix), and plugged its Ethernet port straight into the back of the WRT54G2.

It seems I can't use both at the same time.

As soon as I start using the Blu-ray player, the Wi-Fi connection is immediately dropped on all other connected devices and the SSID is no longer visible.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which fixed it, but I changed the broadcast channel from 6 to 11, and plugged the ethernet cable into a different port on the router (it had been in port #1, now it's in #4)

Now it's all working fine.

Comment: If your ISP provided the router then possibly some ports are hardcoded for special uses in the firmware (using firmware modifications done by the ISP). My router also has 4 ports but only 2 are usable because the ISP has reserved the rest for IPTV. You may have been tryin to use a port that's reserved without your knowing, which would explain why using another port fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like your blu-ray player is emitting radio signals that mess up channel 6. That's common with devices like microwaves, but suggests a manufacturing defect in a disc player. If you hadn't already worked around the problem, I would have suggested asking for a warrantee  replacement on the player.